# Using Gauss-Bonnet in a Proof

Tags: differential-geometry

I was wondering if there was a prove of the Poincaré-Hopf index theorem using Gauss-Bonnet I'll really like to see one to understand it better.

Comment: There is, see section $2.2$ in Li's paper http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/li4.pdf